# Collective or individual loops for best performance?

Tags: c, arrays, performance, loops, caching

Say I have `N` contiguous arrays of the same size in C (or any other language - I guess it doesn't matter much). I want to loop over these arrays and perform some operation on each array element. This can be achieved by a single loop since all `N` arrays are of the same size. Is it faster however to do a separate loop for each array, due to the way computer memory works?

For concreteness, let's say that `N` is very large, perhaps several billion, making each array many gigabytes in size. Also, the arrays are really 3D, meaning that a complete "loop over an array" is actually three nested loops. The complexity of the arithmetic that goes into computing the array pointer from the three loop variables is comparable to the complexity of the actual operation on the array element, which is why I dread adding more loops than necessary.

The "obvious" answer is to just write both programs and see which performs the best in my particular situation. I would however like to hear some more thoughtful arguments/guidelines for how to judge this situation, as it is beyond my own programming intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial intuition was that a loop per array would work better, since the data locality will help caching.

Having all the arrays in one loop would pollute the cache (when processing the first array the cache would be (partially) populated by some elements of that array, but at the very next line of code, you will need data for the second array and cache will not be able to help).

The theoretical complexity remains the same in both cases.

---

However, it depends on the number of arrays you have (I am not saying contiguous for now). Having to loop from scratch again and again can beat the cache speedup that the approach of one array per loop can offer, as demonstrated below:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ cat bigloop.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 100000

typedef struct timeval wallclock_t;
void wallclock_mark(wallclock_t *const tptr);
double wallclock_since(wallclock_t *const tptr);

// gcc -Wall -O3 bigloop.c -o bigloop
int main(void)
{
    int a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N], e[N], i;

    wallclock_t  t;
    double  s;

    wallclock_mark(&t);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i * 10 + (i - 2);
        b[i] = i * 9 + (i - 3);
        c[i] = i * 8 + (i - 1);
        d[i] = i * 11 + (i - 5);
        e[i] = i * 5 + (i - 0);
    }
    s = wallclock_since(&t);
    printf("Populating took %.9f seconds wall clock time.\n", s);

    wallclock_mark(&t);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = e[i] + (i - 1);
        b[i] = d[i] + (i + 3);
        c[i] = a[i] - (i + 2);
        d[i] = b[i] + (i - 2);
        e[i] = a[i] + (i - 4);
    }
    s = wallclock_since(&t);
    printf("Load/write took %.9f seconds wall clock time.\n", s);

    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 100000

typedef struct timeval wallclock_t;
void wallclock_mark(wallclock_t *const tptr);
double wallclock_since(wallclock_t *const tptr);

int main(void)
{
    int a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N], e[N], i;

    wallclock_t  t;
    double  s;

    wallclock_mark(&t);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        a[i] = i * 10 + (i - 2);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        b[i] = i * 9 + (i - 3);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        c[i] = i * 8 + (i - 1);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        d[i] = i * 11 + (i - 5);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        e[i] = i * 5 + (i - 0);
    s = wallclock_since(&t);
    printf("Populating took %.9f seconds wall clock time.\n", s);

    wallclock_mark(&t);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        a[i] = e[i] + (i - 1);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        b[i] = d[i] + (i + 3);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        c[i] = a[i] - (i + 2);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        d[i] = b[i] + (i - 2);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        e[i] = a[i] + (i - 4);
    s = wallclock_since(&t);
    printf("Load/write took %.9f seconds wall clock time.\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

where I have left out the time measurements code, which I have [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1651-2/). The results are:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./bigloop 
Populating took 0.000581000 seconds wall clock time.
Load/write took 0.000178000 seconds wall clock time.
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./loop
Populating took 0.001092000 seconds wall clock time.
Load/write took 0.000285000 seconds wall clock time.
```

where you can see the one order of magnitude speedup the all-arrays-in-one-loop gets when populating the arrays. Furthermore, it's faster in processing them too!

---

So, if I were you, I would implement both approaches and measure the times! =)

<sub>PS: Do not fall a victim of premature optimization. If you have a project you want to optimize, profile your code to find the bottleneck and focus on that!</sub>

Comment: I see you didn't disassemble the code - otherwise you would see what happened after -O3 -> all the loops were removed as dead code. So your code proves nothing.

Comment: Thanks Anty for your comment!

Comment: @gsamaras "one order of magnitude speedup"? More like factor of two. So you got best performance using a single loop, but this is opposite to the supposed cache speedup?

Comment: @Anty What do you mean by "ll the loops were removed as dead code"? Do you mean that -O3 compiles the many loops into a single big loop? In that case, where does the performance difference come from?

Comment: No - it means they were removed altogether because a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N] and e[N] are never used as part of any expression that has side effects. It will be enough to output them to console to prohibit this effect. Check assembly with objdump or godbolt.